# TypeError: connection.getAccountInfo is not a function

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token

I am getting an error

```
TypeError: connection.getAccountInfo is not a function
    at getAccount (account.ts:102:1)
```

in method `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount()`
my parameters are

```
const fromTokenAccount1 = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
          connection,
          publicKey,
          mint1,
          publicKey,
          signTransaction
        );
```

Mint is USDC mint address, publickey i am getting from `useWallet()` for the sender. connection is `mainnet`.
Can please where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Connection` object is not available to the `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` method. You can verify this by doing `console.log(connection)` right before you pass it into the method.

One of the reasons this happens is if you use this method in a modal window, as this might be rendered outside of the Solana connection providers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was passing using `const connection = WalletAdapterNetwork.Mainnet;` now passing using `const connection = new Connection(
    "https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/IjcuUmymeTy65r4Z0KPaWfm7hsIC5OFK",
    "confirmed"
  );` and error gone.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Mohammad! Feel free to upvote my answer! 

Comment: i am running low at reputations sorry man